# Math Equation not outputting result I want

Tags: c, math

The purpose of the program is to calculate the volume at each depth. The inputs are the radius and length and in this test case they are 2.1 and 5.6 respectively. I keep getting 0, 1, 2, 3, and 4 for my volume but that's not the right volume, the depth/height is correct so perhaps someone can shed light on whats wrong with my equation below?

[image]

This is the function that calculates the volume

```
int getVolume(double arrplotptr[][col], double *arr2ptr, char *nameptr)
{
    double vol, h, diam, ctr, rad, len, x;
    int i, j;

    rad = arr2ptr[radius];
    len = arr2ptr[length];
    diam = (rad * 2);
    ctr = diam / 100;
    h = 0;

    for (j = 0; j < 100; j++) {
        h = h + ctr;
        arrplotptr[0][j] = h;
    }
    h = 0;

    for (i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
        h = h + ctr;
        x = (rad - h) / rad;
        vol = ((rad * rad) * acos(x) - (rad - h) * (sqrt((2 * rad * h) - (h * h)))) * len;
        arrplotptr[1][i] = vol;
    }
}
```

Comment: Why do you use `ctr = diam / 100;` instead of `ctr = rad / 100;`?

Comment: I see no `return` with an expression in a function declared to return `int`. Undefined behavior.

Comment: Can you turn your code into an MWE? I.e., a main routine that prints out the computed results?

Comment: Also, even if you are returning the volume, it will be cast to an `int` which loses all the benefit of using `double` for your calculations.

Answer (score 2):

I see several issues in your code:

- Why do you use `ctr = diam / 100;` instead of `ctr = rad / 100;`?
- You do not return a value from `getVolume`, if the caller function relies on the return value, you invoke undefined behavior.
- You store the volume of each slice but do not compute the total volume.  You did not post the code that does that, maybe there are problems there too.

Comment: ctr = diam/100 gives the volume of the cylinder up to 100% full. The total volume will be the volume for h = 2 * rad. Given the style, I'd guess that the return value should indicate success rather than volume.

Answer (score 0):

As written by chqrlie, I think you should change

```
ctr = diam / 100;
```

with

```
ctr = rad / 100;
```

And, as written by EOF, the function is defined as "int" but returns no value; You should redefine it as "void" or return an integer value.

I add that it doesn't seem necessary to double loop: in each iteration you can calculate "h", "x", "vol" and save the two values of "arrplotptr".

I propose to simplify the function as follows

```
void getVolume (double arrplotptr[][col], double arr2ptr[])
 {
   double const rad = arr2ptr[radius];
   double const len = arr2ptr[length];
   double const ctr = rad / 100;

   int     i;
   double  h;

   for ( i = 0, h = ctr ; i < 100 ; ++i, h+=ctr )
    {
      arrplotptr[0][i] = h;
      arrplotptr[1][i] = ((rad * rad) * acos((rad - h) / rad) 
              - (rad - h) * (sqrt((2 * rad * h) - (h * h)))) * len;
    } 
}
```